# 2 Form Submission shows same result AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jsp

I have 2 forms in my jsp page, myform2 and myform3. I have used AJAX to show the result on the same page. When I was doing it only for myform2, it was working fine, but as soon as I did the same for myform3, click on button of myform3 works fine but when I click submit for myform2, it also displays result of myform3, i.e, I get 2 results on my page both of myform3 rather than one of myform2 and other of myform3.
Here is my jsp code:

```
<form id="myform2" name="myform2"
            action="/AWSCustomerJavaWebFinal/ServiceInstances" method="get"
            onsubmit="return messagePrompt()">
            <select name="availableRegion" id="availableRegion"
                style="width: 142px; margin-left: 15px;" class="btn btn-primary">
                <option value="sr">Select Region</option>
                <option value="us-east-1">North Virginia</option>
                <option value="us-west-2">Oregon</option>
                <option value="us-west-1">North California</option>
                <option value="eu-west-1">Ireland</option>
                <option value="eu-central-1">Frankfurt</option>
                <option value="ap-southeast-1">Singapore</option>
                <option value="ap-northeast-1">Tokyo</option>
                <option value="ap-southeast-2">Sydney</option>
                <option value="sa-east-1">Sao Paulo</option>
            </select> <input type="submit" value="View Status" id="button2"
                class="btn btn-primary"><br></br>
            <div id='content'></div>
        </form>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var form = $('#myform2');
                form.submit(function() {

                    $.ajax({
                        type : form.attr('method'),
                        url : form.attr('action'),
                        data : form.serialize(),
                        success : function(data) {
                            var result = data;
                            $('#content').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
        </script>
    </div>
    <br>
</fieldset>
<div class="container">
    <form id="myform3" name="myform3" action="viewSchedule.jsp"
        method="get">
        <br> To view Schedule: <input type="submit"
            value="View Schedule" id="button3" class="btn btn-primary">

        <div id='content1'></div>
    </form>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var form = $('#myform3'); 
                form.submit(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type : form.attr('method'),
                        url : form.attr('action'),
                        data : form.serialize(),
                        success : function(data) {
                            var result = data;
                            $('#content1').html(result); 
                        } 
                    }); 

                    return false; 
                });
        </script> 
</div>
```

Comment: You have 1 global variables having same name as `form` hence later one will override the value of `var form = $('#myform2');`, Try changing value of variables. Also note, there is no point loading `jQuery` library twice..

Comment: yes you need to just change the variable name in form2 or form3. because you have used global variable. if you change the variable name in one of the form the issue will be fixed

Comment: Thanks, changing the variable name works fine.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a library, and should only be loaded once. You have a second script reference to `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` that will overwrite the existing jQuery instance. This may be removed entirely.

What you're doing could also be achieved with a single binding to both forms. The exact implementation could be handled in several ways, but easiest would be if you changed `#content` and `#content1` to use a common class:

```
// target both forms at once
var forms = $('#myform2, #myform3');

forms.submit(function() {

   // get only the form being submitted
   var form = $(this); 

   $.ajax({
     type: form.attr('method'),
     url: form.attr('action'),
     data: form.serialize(),
     success: function(result) {
        form.find('.content').html(result);
     }
   });

   return false;
});
```

Note that the above code would have to be executed at a point when both `#myform2` and `#myform3` are available in the DOM, which means you can't just put this where the `#myform2` binding currently is, but if you put it where the `#myform3` binding is, you will probably be fine. To be sure that all of the elements in the document are available to javascript manipulation, you may defer your script until DOMReady, by wrapping it in the jQuery DOMReady listener, shorthand `$()`:

```
$(function() {

   // all code here

});
```

Comment: I guess the issue is with `var form`

Comment: @RayonDabre: +1, good catch, I didn't note that the variable was being used inside the callback. Otherwise it would be unproblematic, albeit perhaps poor practice. Oh well. My suggested solution would address that as well.

Comment: Yeah...Can we call this _DRY_ approach ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing this also, but it didn't work.

Comment: @DavidHedlund It redirected to another page and showed result there.

Comment: @ArushiTomar: Oh, my bad. I omitted the `return false` from your code, so the form would've proceeded to carry out the default behavior. Fixed.

Comment: @DavidHedlund still doesn't work, doesn't show the result on webpage, where it does show it on the eclipse console which means that form is being submit, but the result is not displayed. I changed both the <div id='content' and content2 to div id='content'.

Comment: @ArushiTomar: Yes, ID should be unique within the document, so I changed to `class="content"`. Note that this also means that the jQuery selector must be `.content` and not `#content`.